# Automated browser requests: detection, ajax vs iframes

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, http-headers, google-chrome-extension

I am doing automated (at predefined times, without user intervention) requests, and it seems that xmlHttpRequest includes additional http headers.

As i would like the server NOT to be able to identify these requests are automated (must be exactly the same as normal user navigation), do i need to instead use iframes, or can i still use ajax and remove/set these headers? (currently using jQuery)

If i do need to use iframes, since my 'app' is a chrome extension, are there any issues i should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify some headers using [setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29). According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method), you cannot set the following headers:

- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Cookie
- Cookie2
- Content-Transfer-Encoding
- Date
- Expect
- Host
- Keep-Alive
- Referer
- TE
- Trailer
- Transfer-Encoding
- Upgrade
- User-Agent
- Via

> or if the start of header is a
>   case-insensitive match for Proxy- or
>   Sec- (including when header is just
>   Proxy- or Sec-).

If that is not what you want, then you must use an iframe, I do that with the fb-exporter Chrome Extension. Later on I changed it to XHR since it just works.

Comment: Thanks, that may be useful. `Referer` may be an issue (so is with an iframe, but i can get around that). How about `X-Requested-With` - can it be removed at all?

Comment: Any header that starts with x- is non-standard, so it can be removed by setting it to empty string I believe. `req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', '')`

Comment: (On chrome and FF) I'm still seeing the header being sent, just empty :|

Comment: I don't know if Chrome blocks you from setting it, but are you calling `setRequestHeader` right after you call `open()` ?

Comment: I used jQuery, and tried via both the $.ajax() parameters and onBeforeSend function